# Specified cast is not valid.. in sql data record

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have used following code to insert the list values to table. 
I refer this link to impletement this procedure. [Passing list of objects to a SQL Server stored procedure and insert records using asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097281/passing-list-of-objects-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-and-insert-records-usin)

```
private List<SqlDataRecord> GetHotelList(List<HotelInfo> list, string RequestRef)
        {
            List<SqlDataRecord> datatable = new List<SqlDataRecord>();

            SqlMetaData[] sqlMetaData = new SqlMetaData[12];
            sqlMetaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("HotelID", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlMetaData[1] = new SqlMetaData("RequestReference", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
            sqlMetaData[2] = new SqlMetaData("FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlMetaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlMetaData[4] = new SqlMetaData("Nights", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlMetaData[5] = new SqlMetaData("MealPlan", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
            sqlMetaData[6] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            sqlMetaData[7] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlMetaData[8] = new SqlMetaData("Status", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlMetaData[9] = new SqlMetaData("StarCategory", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlMetaData[10] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlMetaData[11] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedUserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);

            foreach (var info in list)
            {
                SqlDataRecord row = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);
                int? hotelId = GetHoteId(info.HotelName);
                row.SetValues(hotelId, RequestRef, info.FromDate, info.ToDate, info.Nights, info.MealPlan, info.StarCategory, info.Status, info.LastUpdatedBy, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, info.CreatedUserId);
                datatable.Add(row);
            }

            return datatable;
        }
```

But I am getting 'specified cast is not valid' error in row.SetValues(). Can I get any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: having **hotelId** as nullable is nut the best idea.

Comment: Having a [mcve] we could actually examine would help a lot but at first glance, you appear to be passing parameters to `SetValues` in a different order to the metadata array - specifically, you seem to be passing `Status` in a position where `LastUpdatedDate` might be expected to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks the order of your values is off. Specifically, you have:

```
sqlMetaData[5] = new SqlMetaData("MealPlan", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
sqlMetaData[6] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
sqlMetaData[7] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlMetaData[8] = new SqlMetaData("Status", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlMetaData[9] = new SqlMetaData("StarCategory", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlMetaData[10] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

But while you insert

```
info.MealPlan,
info.StarCategory,
info.Status,
info.LastUpdatedBy,
DateTime.Now,
DateTime.Now
```

Notice how StarCategory, Status and LastUpdatedBy are out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Well you did not show us the SQL Sever part which is vital in this case.  Please update your question with the corresponding SQL Server code table to which you are inserting and the stored procedure you are using would be the best.

You are probably doing some value conversion for which the `CAST` ([Cast and Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

row.SetValues method want object

try this

```
row.SetValues(new object[]{hotelId, RequestRef, info.FromDate, info.ToDate, info.Nights, info.MealPlan, info.StarCategory, info.Status, info.LastUpdatedBy, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, info.CreatedUserId});
```